# How to get CSS to select ID that begins with a string (not in Javascript)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If the HTML has elements like this:

```
id="product42"
id="product43"
...
```

How do I match all of those id's starting with "product"?

I've seen answers that do this exactly using javascript, but how to do it with only CSS?

Answer (score 513, accepted):

```
[id^=product]
```

`^=` indicates "starts with". Conversely, `$=` indicates "ends with".

The symbols are actually borrowed from Regex syntax, where `^` and `$` mean "start of string" and "end of string" respectively.

See [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) for full information.

Comment: Thanks for the method and explanation, I've edited my question so its more clear.  Out of curiosity, is there a way to match a string inside of the id's string?

Comment: See [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings), they explain it better than I could!

Comment: @itamar: I appreciate your attempt at editing my answer, but quote are only required if the value contains characters that are not a valid identifier. `product` is clearly a valid identifier, and therefore needs no quotes.

Comment: The specificity of this type of selector is very low

Comment: How about "does not start with" and "does not end with"?

Comment: @Emerald214 `:not([id^=product])`

Answer (score 87):

I'd do it like this:

```
[id^="product"] {
  ...
}
```

Ideally, use a class. This is what classes are for:

```
<div id="product176" class="product"></div>
<div id="product177" class="product"></div>
<div id="product178" class="product"></div>
```

And now the selector becomes:

```
.product {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Blender, thanks, I chose the other answer because it explains a bit more to me and understand the symbols being used.  I can't use classes for this scenario, otherwise, yes it would be nicer.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

```
[id^=product]{property:value}
```

Answer (score 4):

I want to share this solution too, maybe in the future it could help someone.

As the others said you can write `[id^=product]` for `id`

But we can give an example for the `class` as well:
`[class^="product-"]` which indicates classes starts with product
and also `*` like this `[class*="product-"]`

This is a simple example :

```
/* Icons */
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'mk-font' !important;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

good luck ...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is another CSS selector that does the same thing .
The syntax is as follows :

```
[id|="name_id"]
```

This will select all elements ID which begins with the word enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: How did you notice? reference?

Comment: Doc for this here : https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors
This should select all id which start or equal to "name_id"

Comment: `att|=val` is NOT the same as `att^=val`.  From the reference mentioned : The `|=` selector "Represents an element with the att attribute, its value either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" **immediately followed by "-"**. "  So an id like "product42" would not be matched by `|=`, but "product-42" would.