# Find all ID's that begin with item

Tags: jquery, find, element

I have a bunch of elements on my site (dynamically created). E.g:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="item5" name="item5">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="item2" name="item2">
...
```

I do not know how many Items there are. I only know that the ID-Name is always "itemX" (X stand for a number that I don't know.)

On Button Click I want loop through the site and that it writes alle founded ID that begins wit "item..." in a text input. (hidden field)

Any Ideas, how I can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get CSS to select ID that begins with a string (not in Javascript)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496645/how-to-get-css-to-select-id-that-begins-with-a-string-not-in-javascript)

Comment: how can a single input be both a hidden field and a text input?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with *`attribute starts`* with selector,

```
$("#thatHiddenElement").val($("input[id^=item]").map(function(){ 
  return this.value 
}).get());
```

The above code will set the value in the hidden text box like `"hai,hello"`

Comment: very nice solution

Comment: It don't work. The fields stays empty. `code`$("#btn_make").on("click", function() { 
  
  $("#itemstring").val($("input[id^=item]").map(function(){ 

      return this.value 
   }).get());
   
});`code`

Comment: @DragonStyle This should work. You must be doing wrong somewhere. Can you create a demo of your problem here in jsfiddle.net ? So that it would be helpful for us to fix your problem.

Comment: That only returns a comma when I click "make" (?)

Comment: @DragonStyle you have to type something in the text boxes there.

Comment: Hm, thats is not what I want. I want to geht the IDs. Not that values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110752/discussion-between-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy-and-dragonstyle).

Comment: The code, we figured out, did not work with dynamically generated elements. Did someone have an Idea why: https://jsfiddle.net/qoyy8wpb/5/