# How to select multiple ids in CSS?

Tags: css

How can I select multiple IDs in CSS? For example:

```css
#test_id_*{

}
```

```html
<div id="test_id_10"></div>
<div id="test_id_11"></div>
```

Comment: Are the ID's generated through jquery or just different static id's on the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get CSS to select ID that begins with a string (not in Javascript)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496645/how-to-get-css-to-select-id-that-begins-with-a-string-not-in-javascript)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
 on the `id` attribute:

```
[id^='test_id_'] { color: red; }
```

Description:

> `[attr^=value]` represents an element with an attribute name of `attr` and whose first value is prefixed by "value".

Answer (score 9):

To use one `css` for multiple `id` or `class`, you need to separate them with `,`

```
#test_id_10,
#test_id_11
{
    //some style
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want add same style to multi div, it's better to use class, but if you have your own reason for this, the better way is to wrap all your div's on one div:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="id1">
    <p>
      First Div!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="id2">
     <p>
        Second Div!
     </p>
   </div>
  <div id="id3">
    <p>
      Third Div!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and set your style like this in your CSS:

```
.wrap > div {
  color:blue;
 }
```

Comment: This will work only for properties which are inherited.

Answer (score 1):

### If they have the same style, then why can't they have the same class?

```css
.iknow{
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test_id_10" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_11" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_12" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_13" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_14" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_15" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_16" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_17" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_18" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_19" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_20" class="iknow"></div>
<div id="test_id_21" class="iknow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it like following

```
#test_id_10,#test_id_11{

}
```

Comment: No, that won't scale for additional IDs

Answer (score 0):

You can separate them by commas to apply css on multiple ids.

```
<div id="test_id_10"></div>
<div id="test_id_11"></div>
```

You can select them by:

```
#test_id_10, #test_id_11 {
// your css values
}
```

Comment: How would I scale this to 100 elements with IDs of the form `test_id_nnn`?

Comment: You can use class if you want to apply same css to all elements.
But if you want to use multiple ids, you can use jquery for selecting multiple ids with same pattern.

$(function() {
    $("input[id^='test_id_']").test_id_({
       // your css
    });
});

Comment: Why would somebody introduce jQuery to apply styling? Why not use pure CSS for this?

Answer (score -3):

```
#test_id_10 { //your styling }
```

Here is the basics in W3 schools https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp

Comment: The OP wants to know how to write a rule for **multiple** IDs which start with `test_id_`.