# How to edit two IDs?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble adding more than 1 ID to my CSS. I would like for the box border to have four different buttons (the hover effect) and three gradient buttons (ex: play, pictures, ect.).

Here is my HTML

```
<h2><a id="hover-1" href="">Hover Effect 1</a></h2>
<h2><a id="hover-2" href="">Hover Effect 2</a></h2>
<a href="" id="play">Play</a><br/>
<a href="" id="picture">Picture</a><br/>
```

And here is the CSS

```
<style>

/* Gradient*/
body {
  padding: 3em;
}
#play {
  color: blue;
  font: bold 3em/1.5 , sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
}
#play:hover {
  color: hotPink;
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #play {
    background-color: skyBlue;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hotPink 0%, orange 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-position: 100% 0;
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: .1s .2s;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  #play:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: transparent;
    transition: .4s 0;
  }
}

/*Box Border*/
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  color:black;
  font: 16px/1 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: flex;
  clear: both;
}


h2 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
}

a, a > span {
  position: relative;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 24px;
}
a:before, a:after, a > span:before, a > span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

#hover-1 {
  padding: 10px;
}
#hover-1:before, #hover-1:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
#hover-1:before {
  border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
#hover-1:after {
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
#hover-1:hover:before, #hover-1:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

</style>
```

I have tried to add the two IDs to all of the css like such,

```
#play, #picture {
  color: blue;
  font: bold 3em/1.5 , sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
}
```

But for some reason that dint work.
If you can help, thanks!
And dont hesitate to ask questions!

Comment: `#play, #picture {}` this code block should work... If not how it not works ?

Comment: Similar to [How to select multiple ids in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648365/how-to-select-multiple-ids-in-css), but it doesn't address why the block might not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #play {
    background-color: skyBlue;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hotPink 0%, orange 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-position: 100% 0;
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: .1s .2s;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
```

The `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` min ratio is set at 0 so `#play` will always have this style.
So you can either add `#picture` to this styling or remove this styling and add `#picure` to:

```
#play, #picture {
  color: blue;
  font: bold 3em/1.5 , sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
}
```

Full CSS:

```
/* Gradient*/
body {
  padding: 3em;
}
#play, #picture {
  color: blue;
  font: bold 3em/1.5 , sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
}
#play:hover {
  color: hotPink;
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #play:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: transparent;
    transition: .4s 0;
  }
}
#picture:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: transparent;
    transition: .4s 0;
  }
}

/*Box Border*/
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  color:black;
  font: 16px/1 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: flex;
  clear: both;
}


h2 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
}

a, a > span {
  position: relative;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 24px;
}
a:before, a:after, a > span:before, a > span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

#hover-1, #hover-2 {
  padding: 10px;
}
#hover-1:before, #hover-1:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
#hover-1:before {
  border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
#hover-1:after {
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
#hover-1:hover:before, #hover-1:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
#hover-2:before, #hover-2:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
#hover-2:before {
  border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
#hover-2:after {
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
#hover-2:hover:before, #hover-2:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

EDIT: Changed CSS for comment

Comment: And how about for the box border css. how can i add two ids there? because when i do it it messes everything up

Comment: Its a bit messy but i would just repeat the process for #hover-2

Answer (score 0):

Using that selector syntax should work just fine, as you can see in this example:

```css
#elem1, #elem2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="elem1">Element 1</p>
  <p id="elem2">Element 2</p>
</div>
```

That said, the idea of `id`s is to identify a unique element and unique style. If you want to share styles between multiple elements, you should use a `class`. You can still have an unique `id` combined with the class, like so:

```css
.text {
  color: red;
}

#elem1 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
#elem2 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text" id="elem1">Element 1</p>
  <p class="text" id="elem2">Element 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would love to do classes but with the website builder im using (ClickFunnels) its easier to get the id instead of class name. And when i do use that selector syntax it messes everything up.