# Make the only one CSS style instead multiple css styles

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have multiple css styles:

```
form#reply_form-c1r1.odgovor div#cmtforms-c1r1 input{color:red}
form#reply_form-c2r1.odgovor div#cmtforms-c2r1 input{color:red}
form#reply_form-c3r1.odgovor div#cmtforms-c3r1 input{color:red}
form#reply_form-c4r1.odgovor div#cmtforms-c4r1 input{color:red}
```

and I want to make the one css style like this

```
form[id^="reply_form-c"]r1.odgovor div[id^="cmtforms-c"]r1 input{color:red}
```

But this code, doesn't work..

**What I missed?**

Comment: `[id^="..."]r1` will not work. `[id^="..."][id$="r1"]` will.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the elements a class and use that not all the id's etc. `class="red-block"` and then in CSS `.red-block{color:red;}`

Example:

```css
.red-block {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-block">Howdy</div>
<span class="red-block">spanner</span>
<button type="button" class="red-block">Make me do it</button.
```

Comment: OK, good thought but I can't use that. I need to use wildcard css like I show in my example.

Comment: That then becomes a different question and is  a duplicate: here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11496658/125981

Comment: That also show the "endswith" example

Comment: And here is a "contains" example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157322/125981

Comment: FWIW and IMHO using ID's in any way to style is kind of an anti-pattern.