# Playwright Python Iframe not able able to locate and fill elements

Tags: testing, iframe, playwright, playwright-python

[THE DOM Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrOcp.png)Playwright using python - I am trying to identify an iframe whose name and id are appended with text that is changing dynamically. I am trying to get the iframe and then locate and fill in the elements inside the iframe.

The piece of code that I am using:

```
    def switch_frame(self):
        print("entering switch frame")
        iframe_element = self.page.frame_locator('iframe#cardinal-stepUpIframe-1694715431969')
        print("iframe_element:")
        print(type(iframe_element))
        time.sleep(5)
        iframe_element.get_by_placeholder(" Enter Code Here").fill("1234")
```

The following is the result when the above piece of code is executed:
entering switch frame
iframe_element:
<class 'playwright.sync_api._generated.FrameLocator'>
`

```
return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
  File "/home/ezetap/Downloads/EzeAuto/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 482, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
  File "/home/ezetap/Downloads/EzeAuto/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 97, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=
```

========================== logs ===========================
waiting for frame_locator("iframe#cardinal-stepUpIframe-1694715431969").get_by_placeholder(" Enter Code Here")
`

I am expecting to be able to fill the input field. I think the piece of code is breaking because the iframe id is dynamically changing and we are not able to locate the iframe successfully.

I do not want to use async(await ) methods in my project.

Comment: Have you tried the ["beginning of string" selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496645/how-to-get-css-to-select-id-that-begins-with-a-string-not-in-javascript) `'[id^="cardinal-stepUpIframe-"]'`? It's a good idea to share the site because there may be other reasons the element isn't selectable or better approaches available.