# Access dynamic id generated each time tested by using locator in playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

What I'm trying to achieve is to go to an email inbox, pick the first email, which is where the otp is sent, and then extract the OTP and check if the one entered by the user matches it or not.
Something like:

```
import { test } from "@playwright/test";
test("otp-test", async ({ page }) => {
    //someEmailURL is the url address of the inbox
    await page.goto("someEmailURL");
    // 12345687-874512, this part of the ID varies each time tested as a new email is generated
    await page.locator("tr#row_random-12345687-874512").getByRole("cell", 
    { name: "OTP Verification"}).click();`your text`
}
```

How can I handle tr#row_random-12345687-874512, given `12345687-874512` this varies everytime I test?
Also now the element is divided into multiple cells as it's in a table format. I want to take that row which has both `name:"just now"` and `name: "OTP Verification"` Is there any way to do that?
This test is written in playwright.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get CSS to select ID that begins with a string (not in Javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496645/how-to-get-css-to-select-id-that-begins-with-a-string-not-in-javascript)

Comment: Ideally, don't select using CSS selectors. They're [discouraged](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#test-user-visible-behavior) in Playwright. Providing the actual page or its HTML would avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) and allow people to provide the best possible solution. Now, if you're sure that CSS selectors really are the best approach, then you can use `tr[id^="row_random-"]`, assuming `row_random` is a unique prefix in your markup. Please [edit] your post to fix your syntax error.

Comment: No, it does not I wanted to know how to access the dynamic IDs generated on every test via playwright locator, or any other playwright api if possible.

Comment: If `tr[id^="row_random-"]` doesn't work, can you share more context to motivate why not? There's no reason it shouldn't work based on the extremely limited information you've provided. Considering you responded less than a minute after I made the suggestion, can you confirm you actually ran the solution? What was the error or undesirable behavior that occurred? Thanks.

Comment: Right! It worked, an error was showing and I thought it wasn't working. Thank you for the correction.